# Using nifi - I have to invoke an API with multiple API endpoints

Tags: apache-nifi

I have similar request, I have to invoke an API with multiple endpoints. With the same API key.
Example -

1. https://imwebapi/user_info?Api_Key=XXXXXXXXXXX
2. https://imwebapi/class_info?Api_Key=XXXXXXXXXXX
3. https://imwebapi/subject_info?Api_Key=XXXXXXXXXXX
4. https://imwebapi/grade_info?Api_Key=XXXXXXXXXXX
   I just dont want to copy/paste my nifi processors multiple times. Is there a way?

Comment: the `url` parameter of [InvokeHttp](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/) processor supports expression language - so you could build url dynamically.

Comment: Any references? I was trying to find a good example(sample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple setups here, and since you have the same key for all api`s you should put this into Variable, parameter context or even as a new attibute.

**1 - using attribute :**
You trigger the flow with generateflowfile >> updateattribute(create the key attribute - that you pass to your url)
[image]

**2 - You ad a variable to you PG / canvas and use it the same way you used the attribute**
[image]

[image]
3 - here is how you use the key attribute/variable in yout http request

There are more ways to tackle this, but this would a basic option